# Datepicker issue with twitter Bootstrap in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I m trying to add a datepicker in my modal, but unable to change the value in input field.

This is my code

```
 modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
      $timeout(function () {

            $('#disb_date').datetimepicker({
                  debug: false,
                  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                  maxDate: new Date()
            }).on('dp.change', function () {
                $(this).find('input').trigger('keyup');
            });
     }, 500);
});
```

I somehow managed to change the input field value by adding timeout, but I  am still confused if this is a right way?

Comment: no, do not use the timeout, you have to callback'it after your modal opened, is this `#disb_date` element type input and rendered ok?

Comment: @oserk if I don't use timeout then the value is not getting set for #disb_date element

Comment: @oserk yes this #disb_date element  type is input and its getting rendered when using timeout.

Comment: Why are you mixing jquery with angular? why not use the angular-bootstrap date-picker?

Comment: @Sudakatux ui is not so good for angular date-picker.